# Access Firebase with secrets rules by android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase which is configured secrets database (read == false and write == false). When I use ESP8266 and create app by appinventor, It just need Firebase URL and Secrets key (I get it in database secrets) to read and write data. But when I create app by android studio by myself, I must change the rules (read == true and write == true) to access data. Can you help me access the firebase with rules (read == false and write == false) by android studio?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK for Android does not have a way to initialize the client with a classic database secret. This is because that approach would give the Android app administrative access to your entire Firebase project, which allows the users of the app to do whatever they want. This is an anti-pattern, since the vast majority of Android apps are built to distribute to users of your app whose access should be controlled through security rules.

So the common solution would be to use Firebase Authentication in your app, and then write your security rules to control the data that the identified users can access. Even if you only use anonymous authentication (which doesn't require your users to sign in), you can already secure your app through these rules better than without authentication.

There **is** an Admin SDK for Firebase, which grants the users administrative access to the Firebase project (similar to what the secret key does for you now). But that SDK is not available for use in Android apps, to prevent it from being used to accidentally open up your project to regular users. Instead the Admin SDK is available to run on trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

What you could do is use the Admin SDK on such an environment, and then expose controlled end points (i.e. your own API) to your Android app. A simple example f that would be through [callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). But there too, you will have to ensure that you secure access to that custom API, so that you don't accidentally expose more data than you should.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I need to create an app to connect to firebase for users owner their firebase. So if I use admin SDK, one app will be control 1 firebase database for 1 hour, it is not flexible.